# PHP isset does not populate radio element in form

Tags: php, mysql

I inherited a PHP form that uses session and MySQL that features a radio element that is supposed to check for which value the radio value currently is and mark it as "checked" to populate the correct radio element based on that record in the database.  All of the other form elements populate correctly, it's just this radio element that is not being checked based on the database value of 0 or 1.

Here is the code, I appear to be missing something?

```
<label class="radioSublabel_Narrow" for="User_Update_group_4_Accepted__1"> Yes&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="User_Update_group_4_Accepted" id="User_Update_group_4_Accepted__1" value="1" class="formRadioField_Standard" <?php if (!(strcmp((isset($_GET["invalid"])?ValidatedField("userupdate","User_Update_group_4_Accepted"):""),"1"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> tabindex="4" title="Please enter a value.">
</label>
<label class="radioSublabel_Narrow" for="User_Update_group_4_Accepted__2"> No&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="User_Update_group_4_Accepted" id="User_Update_group_4_Accepted__2" value="0" class="formRadioField_Standard" <?php if (!(strcmp((isset($_GET["invalid"])?ValidatedField("userupdate","User_Update_group_4_Accepted"):""),"0"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> tabindex="5">
</label>
```

Comment: From what I see I think the `:` column was pit in the wrong place is your code showing any errors?

Comment: Why are you using `strcmp()` instead of just comparing with `==`?

Comment: Is `$_GET['invalid']` set?

Comment: No errors, nothing.  I didn't use strcmp(), I inherited the code.  The entire thing is confusing to me...any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input element was missing the actual database column reference:

$row_SecurityAssistMSFields["Accepted"]

Here is what was missing in the context of the rest of the code:

```
<?php if (!(strcmp((isset($_GET["invalid"])?ValidatedField("userupdate","User_Update_group_4_Accepted"):"".$row_SecurityAssistMSFields["Accepted"]  .""),"this"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> tabindex="4" title="Please enter a value.">
```